# How to install custom libraries, and use them?

Tags: ihaskell

I have been trying to install some libraries, `csv` and `hs-gchart`. I know that IHaskell has alternatives for charting but I just wanted to try to install something.

I'm using Gibianski's docker image.

I already tried to do a `cabal install` in the docker container, but results that docker is not installed so I ssh'd into the container and installed it. Still cannot import any of these libraries.

Then I tried to install with `stack build csv hs-gchart`, still no luck.

What would be the straightforward/correct way to install a library and use it from an IHaskell notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking to Andrew Gibiansky on IHaskell's Gitter, he recommended me to fork/clone the repo, add `stack install <library>` in the `Dockerfile`, and then do a `docker build -t my-ihaskell /path/to/the/IHaskell/repo`. After that just `docker run my-ihaskell`.

Now the libraries work as expected. (`hs-gchart` fails, but thats another story)